# Everywhere on my server using gzip is showing black question marks

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm running Apache + PHP and all the places in my site that use gzip (E.g. CSS in WordPress) no longer loads and just shows a black question mark. I have no idea where to look for the error.

[image]

My test script is this:

```
<?php
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 1209600 ) );
header( 'Content-type: text/css; charset=UTF-8' );

$http_accept_encoding = $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"];

if ( strpos( $http_accept_encoding, 'x-gzip' ) !== FALSE ) {
        $encoding = 'x-gzip';
} else if( strpos($http_accept_encoding,'gzip') !== FALSE ) {
        $encoding = 'gzip';
} else {
        $encoding = FALSE;
}

if ( $encoding ) {
        header( 'Content-Encoding: ' . $encoding );
        echo "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
}

$output = 'Hellooooooooooooooo World';


if ( $encoding ) {
        echo gzcompress( $output, 9 );
} else {
        echo $output;
}
```

And the output is here:

http://brandonwamboldt.ca/css.php

It's also inconsistent, sometimes it will load properly sometimes it won't

Comment: What was the last thing you changed just before it stopped working.

Comment: I updated the OS via yum update

Comment: Then you need to find out which config file it changed, and revert those changes.  Look around the Apache and PHP config files and find out which have been modified.

Comment: ...more likely to be a change in the libs than the config to cause this. That it's only returning a single character makes me think that maybe gzcompress is returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly what caused the issue, but I rolled back to PHP 5.4.3 from PHP 5.4.4 and the problem no longer occurs (Same config files). Putting PHP 5.4.4 back causes the issue again.